# get error when downloading the chromium src code

Tags: shell, chromium

I try to download the chromium source code and compile it on my mac.
According to the instructions:

> https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/mac_build_instructions.md

I did everything before:

```
$ fetch chromium
```

but when I try to download the chromium, it gives the error:

```
fetch chromium: Get chromium: unsupported protocol scheme ""
```

Any ideas, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I think what happens is someother command override the fetch command. I'm not really sure. But since it is an executable command, I just use the absolute path of the fetch file to run it and it works.